# Creating a validation for a switchClass on hover so the animations are tied to when the mouse enters and leaves the div

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

Using a hover function, I have some divs that switch classes when the mouse enters and leaves the parent div. The problem is that if the mouse leaves the webpage, the switchClass stays toggled in the state that I want to only happen when the mouse is hovering in the parent div.

So I have a series of rows. They're built out with a container, then two divs side by side, child1 and child2. When the mouse is not in the container, child1 is 100% width and child2 is hidden by overflow: hidden. When the mouse hovers over the container, child1 switches to the class child1-hover and child2 slides into view, and vice versa.

I have it working with hover(), but I would rather there be some sort of validation using mouseEnter and mouseLeave because if I scroll too fast over the rows or if my mouse leaves the webpage, the switch gets switched, so when I'm not hovering over the container the child has child1-hover applied and vice versa.

Here are my issues:

1. I don't like that when I scroll too fast or my mouse leaves the webpage, the hover state in my switchClass becomes the non-hover state. See this version: https://jsfiddle.net/sling/g7xLn1ut/6/
2. I have to use classes, not IDs because there's like 30 rows on this webpage, so then I have to use a `$('.container').hover(function() { ->>>$(this).find<<<-` just to make things a little more complex
3. Even when using mouseenter and mouseleave, I still have the same issue where when I use switchClass. See this version: https://jsfiddle.net/sling/d6x4sfLn/
4. I don't want this function to slow down my website, so I don't want it like refreshing the page every 10 seconds or anything... So, with that in mind, maybe it's better to have there be a scroll to height activator that makes the child1 switch to child1-hover? This is more of a design/opinion question/a fallback in case what I want to happen is impossible

**please beware, this is just a truncated version of the fiddles linked above**

```
<style>
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .child1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background-image: url('http://www.steves-digicams.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Nikon_D850_Sample_13.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .child2 {
        width: 1px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .child1-hover {
        width: 40%;
        height: 400px;
        background-image: url('http://www.steves-digicams.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Nikon_D850_Sample_13.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        display: inline-block;

    }

    .child2-hover {
        width: 50%;
        height: 400px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="child1">
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed suscipit enim orci. Aenean vulputate scelerisque lorem sagittis lacinia. Nunc vitae massa felis.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="child1">
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed suscipit enim orci. Aenean vulputate scelerisque lorem sagittis lacinia. Nunc vitae massa felis.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="child1">
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed suscipit enim orci. Aenean vulputate scelerisque lorem sagittis lacinia. Nunc vitae massa felis.
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
          $(".container").hover(function() {
            $(this).find(".child1").switchClass("child1", "child1-hover", 300);
            $(this).find(".child1-hover").switchClass("child1-hover", "child1", 300);
            $(this).find(".child2").switchClass("child2", "child2-hover", 300);
            $(this).find(".child2-hover").switchClass("child2-hover", "child2", 300);
          });
        });
</script>
```

Ok and here's version two:

```
<style>
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .child1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background-image: url('http://www.steves-digicams.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Nikon_D850_Sample_13.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .child2 {
        width: 1px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .child1-hover {
        width: 40%;
        height: 400px;
        background-image: url('http://www.steves-digicams.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Nikon_D850_Sample_13.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        display: inline-block;

    }

    .child2-hover {
        width: 50%;
        height: 400px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="child1">
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed suscipit enim orci. Aenean vulputate scelerisque lorem sagittis lacinia. Nunc vitae massa felis.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="child1">
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed suscipit enim orci. Aenean vulputate scelerisque lorem sagittis lacinia. Nunc vitae massa felis.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="child1">
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed suscipit enim orci. Aenean vulputate scelerisque lorem sagittis lacinia. Nunc vitae massa felis.
    </div>
</div>

<script> 
$(".container").mouseenter(function(){
     $(this)
     .find(".child1").addClass("child1-hover", 300).end()
      .find(".child1").removeClass("child1", 300).end()
      .find(".child2").addClass("child2-hover", 300).end()
      .find(".child2").removeClass("child2", 300);
})

$(".container").mouseleave(function(){
     $(this)
     .find(".child1-hover").addClass("child1", 300).end()
      .find(".child1-hover").removeClass("child1-hover", 300).end()
      .find(".child2-hover").addClass("child2", 300).end()
      .find(".child2-hover").removeClass("child2-hover", 300);
})
</script>
```

In version 1, when your mouse leaves the web page or scrolls too fast, the classes get switched so that child1-hover is the active class when you're not hovering in the container div.

In version 2, child1-hover still gets stuck when your mouse leaves the webpage off of the container div, but at least the next time you hover over it the hover state rights itself.

Hopefully part of that makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was actually able to answer this question with help from someone at a dev get-together. Here is our solution:

```
    $(function() {
          $(".project-container").on('mouseenter', function() {
            $(this).find(".image-card").animate({width: "33.33333333%"}, 300);
          });
          $(".project-container").on('mouseleave', function() {
            $(this).find(".image-card").animate({width: "100%"}, 300);
          });
          $("div").on('mouseleave', function(){
           $(this).find(".image-card").clearQueue()
         });
        });
```

Here's the whole thing, but instead of doing a switchClass, we realized we could do an animation. The clearQueue makes sure there's no jitter!

```js
$(function() {
          $(".project-container").on('mouseenter', function() {
            $(this).find(".image-card").animate({width: "33.33333333%"}, 300);
          });
          $(".project-container").on('mouseleave', function() {
            $(this).find(".image-card").animate({width: "100%"}, 300);
          });
          $("div").on('mouseleave', function(){
           $(this).find(".image-card").clearQueue()
         });
        });
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* ‹›‹›‹›‹›‹›‹›‹›‹›‹›‹›‹› Variables ‹›‹›‹›‹›‹›‹›‹›‹›‹›‹›‹› */
/* and mixins */
/* —+—+—+—+—+—+—+—+— Overall Body Styles +—+—+—+—+—+—+—+—+ */
body p, body span, body div {
  font-family: "Work Sans", Times, serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
body a, body strong {
  font-weight: 600;
}
body h1, body h2, body h3, body h4, body h5, body h6 {
  font-weight: 200;
}

/* =≠=≠=≠=≠=≠=≠=≠=≠ Header and Nav styles =≠=≠=≠=≠=≠=≠=≠=≠ */
header #navigation {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

/* ∞8∞8∞8∞8∞8∞8∞8∞8∞8∞8∞ Home styles ∞8∞8∞8∞8∞8∞8∞8∞8∞8∞8∞ */
main .jumbotron {
  padding-top: 7em;
}
main .intro-container {
  height: 10px;
}
main .project-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 500px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
main .project-container .row {
  width: unset;
  height: 100%;
}
main .project-container .row .image-h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  display: block !important;
}
main .project-container .row .image-h2-hide {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
}
main .project-container .row .image-card {
  background-image: url("http://www.steves-digicams.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Nikon_D850_Sample_13.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
main .project-container .row .image-card-hover {
  background-image: url("http://www.steves-digicams.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Nikon_D850_Sample_13.jpg");
  background-image: url("http://www.steves-digicams.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Nikon_D850_Sample_13.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
main .project-container .row .text-card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 66.66666667%;
  padding: 1em 0 1em 2em;
  height: 100%;
}

/* ·•·•··•·•·•·•· ADDITIONAL MEDIA QUERIES ·•·•··•·•· */
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5025f71482.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:200,400,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid project-container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="image-card">
              <h2 class="image-h2">
                This is the second project
              </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="text-card align-bottom">
              <h2>
                Title
              </h2>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin posuere urna non magna imperdiet, non commodo magna finibus. Integer vel lacus sit amet augue imperdiet malesuada. Praesent hendrerit gravida ligula, ac tempor sapien pharetra eget. Maecenas hendrerit, odio quis eleifend vehicula, lacus dui pretium urna, quis facilisis tortor augue eget ipsum. Sed viverra massa vitae pretium tristique. Quisque nec felis mi.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

This is literally copy and pasted from my .html doc, so the snippet isn't... reaaallly working so... sooorrryyy....

buuuuut i didn't want to leave this question unanswered!

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity for a CSS only solution. You can solving the problem and won't need relatively heavy jQuery methods or any JavaScript. We can also simplify the code a little bit.

So, I edited from your JSFiddle code. You just have to apply `:hover` on `.container` for the effects.
Let me show you (below is the entire SCSS):

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;

  .image-h2 {
    top: 50%;
    color: white;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  &:hover .image-h2 {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .image-card {
    background-image: url("http://www.steves-digicams.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Nikon_D850_Sample_13.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }

  &:hover .image-card {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .text-card {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 55%;
    padding-left: 1em;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

}
```